# How to slice multiple sections of dataframe by column name?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get the first column, then add another slice?

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(6,6), columns = list('abcdef'))

          a         b         c         d         e         f
0  0.147163  0.710360  0.069732  0.180949  0.694066  0.639505
1  0.771643  0.094805  0.371702  0.177538  0.089168  0.420331
2  0.431394  0.790537  0.378049  0.402930  0.350409  0.827950
3  0.421411  0.451595  0.703630  0.469526  0.612122  0.076728
4  0.854117  0.302925  0.664647  0.664098  0.959504  0.637122
5  0.659791  0.525526  0.007151  0.448761  0.738571  0.349142
```

I am trying to get column `a`, and all columns after `c`.

This gives me just columns `c,d,e,f`:

```
df.loc[:'a', 'c':]
```

This doesn't work at all:

```
df.loc['a':'a', 'c':]
```

I did a few more attempts but they are just random guessing and I genuinely can't find a solution online.

Note: I am working with a huge real dataframe, so it will be impractical to write individual column names like `df.loc[:,['a','c','d','e','f]]`

Comment: `df.iloc[:, [x for x in range(df.shape[1]) if x!=1]]`?

Answer (score 6):

I understand question how possible select by columns names.

Not easy, because first need positions with [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) and pass it to [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) with select by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
a = df.columns.get_loc('a')
b = df.columns.get_loc('c')
c = len(df.columns)

df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[a, b:c]]
print (df)
          a         c         d         e         f
0  0.210653  0.218035  0.845753  0.456271  0.279802
1  0.932892  0.909715  0.043418  0.707115  0.483889
2  0.444221  0.040683  0.332754  0.947120  0.617660
3  0.368875  0.206132  0.165066  0.361817  0.863353
4  0.509402  0.950252  0.815966  0.322974  0.972098
5  0.987351  0.655923  0.405653  0.257348  0.082653
```

Answer (score 5):

We can do `np.r_`

```
df.iloc[:,np.r_[0,2:df.shape[1]]]
Out[99]: 
          a         c         d         e         f
0  0.147163  0.069732  0.180949  0.694066  0.639505
1  0.771643  0.371702  0.177538  0.089168  0.420331
2  0.431394  0.378049  0.402930  0.350409  0.827950
3  0.421411  0.703630  0.469526  0.612122  0.076728
4  0.854117  0.664647  0.664098  0.959504  0.637122
5  0.659791  0.007151  0.448761  0.738571  0.349142
```

To get the position `get_indexer`

```
df.columns.get_indexer(['c'])
Out[100]: array([2], dtype=int64)
```

---

#### Generalized

```
def drop_from_here_to_there(df, here, there):
    n, m = df.shape
    i, j = df.columns.get_indexer([here, there])
    k = np.r_[0:i+1, j:m]
    return df.iloc[:, k]

drop_from_here_to_there(df, 'a', 'c')

          a         c         d         e         f
0  0.147163  0.069732  0.180949  0.694066  0.639505
1  0.771643  0.371702  0.177538  0.089168  0.420331
2  0.431394  0.378049  0.402930  0.350409  0.827950
3  0.421411  0.703630  0.469526  0.612122  0.076728
4  0.854117  0.664647  0.664098  0.959504  0.637122
5  0.659791  0.007151  0.448761  0.738571  0.349142
```

Comment: @ALollz - get_loc is for one values, get_indexer is for list

Comment: @jezrael that is why I use `df.columns.get_indexer(['a','c'])`

Comment: Forgive the intrusion (-:

Answer (score 2):

#### `drop`

```
df.drop('b', axis=1)

          a         c         d         e         f
0  0.147163  0.069732  0.180949  0.694066  0.639505
1  0.771643  0.371702  0.177538  0.089168  0.420331
2  0.431394  0.378049  0.402930  0.350409  0.827950
3  0.421411  0.703630  0.469526  0.612122  0.076728
4  0.854117  0.664647  0.664098  0.959504  0.637122
5  0.659791  0.007151  0.448761  0.738571  0.349142
```

Comment: I know you answered me literally, but I am working with a huge dataframe, so your solution will end up being `df.drop(['age','transactions','date','location','gender','etc.','etc.','etc.'], axis=1)`. Thanks anyway

Comment: @SCool I'm aware.  I answered this with the thought that others might look up your question with something else in mind.  None the less, I'm still working on another solution that gets at the heart of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of calling dataframes with a list of column names to get the dataframe you want. First, we'll grab a list of all the columns, then just use slicing on the column list, feeding the sliced columns into the dataframe.

```
df.columns.to_list()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

slice

```
cols = df.columns.to_list()
cols = cols[:1] + cols[2:]
cols
['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

call df with cols

```
df[cols]
          a         c         d         e         f
0  0.749754  0.291974  0.638897  0.768337  0.255553
1  0.541221  0.816086  0.472628  0.276530  0.946075
2  0.811953  0.692716  0.729467  0.512503  0.589812
3  0.613418  0.588730  0.497962  0.122666  0.153101
4  0.600428  0.897041  0.643585  0.382276  0.164303
5  0.165782  0.107455  0.149544  0.309294  0.544864
```

Answer (score 1):

One option for flexible column selection is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select_columns.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.select_columns('a', slice('c', None))

          a         c         d         e         f
0  0.147163  0.069732  0.180949  0.694066  0.639505
1  0.771643  0.371702  0.177538  0.089168  0.420331
2  0.431394  0.378049  0.402930  0.350409  0.827950
3  0.421411  0.703630  0.469526  0.612122  0.076728
4  0.854117  0.664647  0.664098  0.959504  0.637122
5  0.659791  0.007151  0.448761  0.738571  0.349142
```